# Unable to show all data from database in the table

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6

```
for(var i =0; i< keys.length;i++){
        var k = keys[i];
        resultUserName.innerHTML = `
        <table class="responsive-table highlight">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Issued Raised By</th>
                <th>Issue For</th>
                <th>Issue Logged Time</th>
                <th>Issue Description</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>${userData[k].raisedBy}</td>
                    <td>${userData[k].issueFor}</td>
                    <td>${userData[k].issueLoggedDate}</td>
                    <td>${userData[k].issueDescription}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        `;
    }
```

I'm trying to retrieve all the data from the DB into a table, it's showing all the data when I console log it but when i display it on the page it is only showing the last entry made, can anyone point out what's wrong in the code above.

Comment: *"can anyone point out what's wrong in the code above"* In each iteration you are overwriting the current content of the element: `resultUserName.innerHTML =  ...`. It seems you want to **append** instead.

Comment: FYI: multiline string declaration with `` will not work in internet explorer 8,9 and probably 10

Comment: Creating HTML this was is a huge security risk because things like `issueDescription` could contain malicious HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build header elements separately outside loop and build each row data in loop as string, finally append to your DOM

```
var innerHtml = '<table class="responsive-table highlight">'+
        '<thead>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<th>Issued Raised By</th>'+
            '<th>Issue For</th>'+
            '<th>Issue Logged Time</th>'+
            '<th>Issue Description</th>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '</thead>'+
        '<tbody>';
for(var i =0; i< keys.length;i++){
    var k = keys[i];
    innerHTML += '<tr>'+
                '<td>${userData[k].raisedBy}</td>'+
                '<td>${userData[k].issueFor}</td>'+
                '<td>${userData[k].issueLoggedDate}</td>'+
                '<td>${userData[k].issueDescription}</td>'+
            '</tr>';
}
resultUserName.innerHtml = innerHTML+"</tbody></table>";
```

Comment: Your answer will be more useful if you explained what you changed and why.

Comment: FYI: multiline string declaration with `` will not work in internet explorer 8,9 and probably 10

Comment: Is it very heavy to append string than using array and joining ??

Comment: @selvakumar by the same logic i'm making a data sort function but i'm unable to configure the else statement that reflects in the resultUserName.innerHTML, how do i make that change because if i put it in the loop it just repeats the else statement .

Comment: couldn't understand, can u show your code to better understanding ??

Answer (score 0):

```
var resultUserName = document.getElementById('resultUserName'); 
var tableHeader = '<table><thead><tr><th>Issued Raised By</th><th>Issue For</th><th>Issue Logged Time</th><th>Issue Description</th></tr></thead><tbody>;
var tableFooter = '</tbody></table>'
var tableBody = '';
for(var i =0; i< keys.length;i++){
  var k = keys[i];
tableBody = tableBody + '<tr>'+
  '<td>${userData[k].raisedBy}</td>'+
  '<td>${userData[k].issueFor}</td>'+
  '<td>${userData[k].issueLoggedDate}</td>'+
  '<td>${userData[k].issueDescription}</td>'+
  '</tr>';
}
resultUserName.innerHTML = tableHeader + tableBody + tableFooter;
```

This should solve your problem. In for loop inner html is getting replaced.